# Android, Xamarin, Rest - how to pass object in the request

Tags: android, spring, rest, xamarin

I have a simple server rest endpoint running Spring -

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/services")
@Transactional
public class CustomerSignInService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDao;

    @RequestMapping("/customer/signin")
    public Customer customerSignIn(@RequestParam(value = "customer") Customer customer) {
        //Some Code Here...
        return customer;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to pass a Customer object from my Xamarin Android App using this method -

```
public JsonValue send(String url, SmartJsonSerializer obj)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "POST";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(obj.toJsonString());
    }

    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            return JsonObject.Load(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

But i keep getting Bad Request Exception (Http Error 400) and obviously my code at the server side is not triggered.

SmartJsonSerializer uses JSON.NET to serialize the Customer object to string -

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Shared
{
    public class SmartJsonSerializer
    {        
        public string toJson()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated,
thnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically if you are posting a complex object to an api like this, you would write it in the request body. You do appear to be doing this on the android side.

I am not familiar with Spring, but it looks that you are expecting `customer` as a url parameter - Try replacing `@RequestParam` with [`@RequestBody`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody).

Comment: @RequestBody did the trick! I was able to play a bit with my junit until i figured it out - thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with it for a while, but apparently the solution may be find in the server side.

If it helps, You can look at this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/services")
@Transactional
public class SomeService {

                @RequestMapping(value = "/user/signin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
                @ResponseBody
                public AppUser signIn(@RequestBody AppUser appUser) {
                                appUser.invoke();
                                return appUser;
                }
}
```